# Menu creation in Activity with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm programming an app based on the Weather App from Udacity Courses.
The app is based in a two activies: one general and other for weather detail with a fragment inside.

I've been experimenting with menu creation and I have and issue that I would like to comment with you all.

AFAIK, If I want to share an option between different fragments, it seems a good idea to put that option in the activity menu instead of the fragment menu, so that's what I'm doing with the Share button.
But I've seen that I have two possible situations:

1) If the menu item inside the xml is declared as showAsAction = never I can create the instance of the ShareActionProvider and the intent inside the onOptionsItemSelected, within the corresponding if sentence (and works fine):

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_share) {
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "nada");
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        return true;                
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

2) If the menu item is declared as showAsAction = always and the Share button is in the action bar, the above doesn't work as the Share button isn't even clickable. I have to declare the above code inside the onCreateOptionsMenu to make things work.
Why is that? Is different the chain of events for creating a menu when is not in the action bar Vs. when it's in it?

Thanks for the answers and excuse me for my english.

Comment: When your action item concerns the content that you can find in the Fragment - you should put it into your fragment menu. Why do you think it's a bad practice?

Comment: Don't think so when only one fragment is related to the menu item but putting it in the Activity instead of the fragment let me share common actions between fragments without having to repeat the code in each related fragment. Just it.